# After() in aspectj

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I am new to aspectj and I had a function which gets the integer variable and adds 100 to it as follows

```
public static void add(int no)
    {
        no=no+100;


    }
```

My aspect is as follows

```
pointcut printMessage(int m) : execution(* add(..)) && args(m);
 after(int m) returning: printMessage(m) {
            System.out.println(m);
}
```

I am calling the function with the value 10. But when I run the code, it returns the result as 10. can any one tell me why it is not returning 110. correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in java an int is not modifiable. If you write

```
int i = 10;
add(i);
System.out.println(i);
```

You will still get 10. So your aspect does what you asked : you pass a variable of value 10 to a function, the fuction does what it wants with its *local* copy, and on return the variable is unchanged

Edit :

If you want to get a modified value, you could pass a modifiable variable like an array, or more simply use the return value (because your current add is a no op) :

Edit 2 here is full test code :

```
public class AspectTest {
    public static int add(int i) {
        return i+100;
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        int j = add(10);
        assertEquals(110, j);
        add(20);
    }
}
```

and :

```
aspect A {
pointcut printMessage() : execution(* add(..));
 after() returning (int m): printMessage() {
            System.out.println(m);
}
}
```

Output :

```
Running ...AspectTest
110
120
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.214 sec
```

Comment: But I am getting the same value...10

Comment: @user3797438 There were syntax errors in my proposed aspect ... post edited. And in my own test I get 110 (with the correct aspect)

Comment: But I wrote `after()` and `returning(int m)`.  `after (int m)` **is** an error ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variant of Serge Ballesta's sample code which makes it even clearer what happens in Java. Primitive types like `int` are immutable, but even some simple built-in object types like `String` are, too. More complex types like `Set` are not, though.

**Driver application with different `add` methods:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Application {
    public static int add(int i) {
        i += 100;
        return i;
    }

    public static String add(String text) {
        text = "#" + text + "#";
        return text;
    }

    public static Set<String> add(Set<String> set) {
        set.add("new element");
        return set;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        add(10);
        add("foo");
        Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<>();
        mySet.add("foo");
        mySet.add("bar");
        add(mySet);
    }
}
```

**Aspect capturing all `add` methods, printing their parameters and results for comparison:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public aspect MyAspect {
    pointcut addMethods(Object parameter) :
        execution(* add(*)) && args(parameter);

    after(Object parameter) returning (Object returnValue): addMethods(parameter) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
        System.out.println("  parameter    = " + parameter);
        System.out.println("  return value = " + returnValue);
    }
}
```

**Console output:**

```
execution(int de.scrum_master.app.Application.add(int))
  parameter    = 10
  return value = 110
execution(String de.scrum_master.app.Application.add(String))
  parameter    = foo
  return value = #foo#
execution(Set de.scrum_master.app.Application.add(Set))
  parameter    = [new element, foo, bar]
  return value = [new element, foo, bar]
```

As you can see, `int` and `String` parameters remain unchanged while the `Set` parameter is mutable and thus updated.